# Not able to get the bitmap from View

Tags: android, android-bitmap

In my application i want the image which is inside the linear layout.So for that i have used

```
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); // this is coming as undefined
    view.buildDrawingCache(); // this is coming as undefined
    Bitmap cache = view.getDrawingCache(); //here am getting null
```

But whenever i debug the code i am getting null at " view.getDrawingCache()".

Code

```
public static void saveLayout(View view) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap cache = view.getDrawingCache();
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ss/file.png");
            cache.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        } finally {
            view.destroyDrawingCache();
        }
    }
```

Usage

```
saveLayout(ll) // here ll is my linear layout
```

Please lemme know where i went wrong

Comment: please post ur logcat warning message here.

Comment: The app is not crashing, but its also not saving the image

Comment: but is there any warning messages.check your logcat once

Comment: i have mentioned that via comments that i m geting view.buildDrawingCache() as undefined

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code?

```
view.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = view.getDrawingCache(true);
```

Also remove:

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I will explain for sure. I would like to know if it worked for you.